# PHP and SQL query to select ids and then use those ids in another query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT(t1.aid),  
   t1.t1Name, 
   t1.startDate, 
   t1.startTime, 
   t1.endDate, 
   t1.endTime, 
   t1.version,
   t5.name,
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 
   ON t2.aid= t1.aid
LEFT JOIN t3 
   ON t3.gid= t2.gid
LEFT JOIN t4 
   ON t4.sid= t3.sid
LEFT JOIN t5 
   ON t5.cid= t4.cid
ORDER BY t5.cid, t4.sNum
```

After running the query, I get an array using a while loop that looks something like this:

```
$values[] = array('name', 'aid', 'startDate', 'startTime', 'endDate', 'endTime', 't1Name', 'version')
```

I would like to use t1.aid to gather another array and add that array to the original array where the t1.aid is to form something like this:

```
$values[] = array('name', 'aid', 'startDate', 'startTime', 'endDate', 'endTime', 't1Name', 'version', 'groups'=> array())
```

Currently I am running another query in a foreach loop and it is quite slow. I was hoping that there is a way to run both queries together (or at least avoid the foreach loop)... The second query is:

```
SELECT
  t6.groupName, 
  t4.sNum, 
  t5.name
FROM t6
LEFT JOIN t2
   ON t2.gid = t6.gid
LEFT JOIN t4
   ON t4.sid = t2.sid
LEFT JOIN t5 
   ON t5.cid = t4.cid
WHERE t2.aid = :aid
```

Note: t1, t2, t3, etc are the same tables in both queries.

Output:

```
$groups[] = array('groupName', 'sNum', 'name')
```

---

Thank you in advance and apologize for formatting errors and/or if it is hard to read.

Comment: Distinct is not a function. For further help please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

Just use sub-SELECTs:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (id) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM table2));

UPDATE table1 SET column1=((SELECT id FROM table2));
```

Everything you can do with a normal `SELECT` you can do with a sub-`SELECT` including `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN`. You just have to make sure that you're returning the appropriate/matching number of columns.